# Excel formula for if when there are 3 alternatives

Tags: excel

I am trying to get a formula that will work for the following:
if Cell A contains X, then Cell B = Cell C +1, but if Cell A contains Y, then Cell B = Cell C +2, but if Cell A contains Z then Cell B = Cell C +3

any help greatly appreciated

Comment: You've done the hardest part: the logic. Now try to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use SWITCH :

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SWITCH-function-47ab33c0-28ce-4530-8a45-d532ec4aa25e

Answer (score 0):

A simple IF statement can be written as below...

```
=IF(A2="X",C2+1,IF(A2="Y",C2+2,IF(A2="Z",C2+3,"")))
```

There are various other approaches to get the desired output. One of them is like below...

```
=IFERROR(CHOOSE(MATCH(A2,{"X","Y","Z"},0),C2+1,C2+2,C2+3),"")
```

Comment: You're welcome Stewart! Conditional formatting works based on if a condition is evaluated to be True. How would you like to use this formula in conditional formatting? If that's a new question, I would suggest you to open a new question with your new requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
=LOOKUP(A1,{"X","Y","Z"},{1,2,3})+C1
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

To use *LOOKUP()*, the input vector must be in alphabetic order.

Comment: That is one of the other approaches I was talking about. Nice. :)

Comment: @sktneer  I like *LOOKUP()*, but it must be **alphabetic**.

Comment: Yeah. That's the downside with this.